# Rails 3 - Help with view, dynamic html attr?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Right now, I have a do loop for a task model in my view:

```
<% @tasks.each do |t| %>
  <div class="task purple">
    <%= link_to t.name, edit_task_path(t) %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I need some help making it so the div class changes based off my model data. I've tried doing this:

```
   <% @tasks.each do |t| %>
      <div class="task " + t.theme>
        <%= link_to t.name, edit_task_path(t) %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
```

But that failed miserably. I then read up on content tag, and was trying something like:

```
content_tag(:div, :class => t.theme){<%= link_to t.name, edit_task_path(t) %>}
```

in the loop but that was rendering it as text.

Anyway, just need some help learning how to change html tag attributes based off the model data? Is this something I would build a view helper for?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason your first approach isn't working, is that you haven't included the ERb tags (`<%= %>`) to output the return value from `t.theme`. In order for that to show up in the output, you need to do this:

```
<% @tasks.each do |t| %>
  <div class="task <%= t.theme%>">
    <%= link_to t.name, edit_task_path(t) %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Remember: ERb knows nothing about HTML, it just scans the entire file for `<% %>` or `<%= %>` tags, and evaluates the ruby code within them.

`content tag` should [work the way you've got it there](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TagHelper.html#method-i-content_tag), but I'd rather pass in the tag's content as the third parameter instead of using a block (I assume you're using Rails 3, the syntax is slightly different in previous versions):

```
<% @tasks.each do |t| %>
  <%= content_tag :div, 
                  :class => "task #{t.theme}", 
                  link_to(t.name, edit_task_path(t)) %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<% @tasks.each do |t| %>
  <div class="task <%= t.theme %>">
    <%= link_to t.name, edit_task_path(t) %>
  </div>
 <% end %>
```

Comment: you forgot the `<%= %>` with `"task #{t.theme}"`